# V8 How to evaluate v8::Module for different v8::Context?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I'm trying to create multiple `v8::Context`s with their own globals initialized by evaluating exactly the same JavaScript module code.

I was hoping to compile the code once, and then run it for every `v8::Context`. However, it looks like `v8::Module` can be run once for a single ``v8::Context`.

Is there any way to compile code once, and then instantiate and evaluate module for multiple `v8::Context`s?